# how do I enable mount propagation in Rancher - Kubernetes feature gates?

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, rke

How can I enable feature gates for my cluster in  Rancher 2.0? I am in need of enabling the `--feature-gates MountPropagation=true`. This will enable me to use storage solutions like StorageOS, CephFS, etc

There are 2 use cases here :

1. If the Rancher is setup already and running?
2. If I am setting up the cluster from scratch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hello and hope this helps someone, After much googling and help from awesome people at Rancher I got the solution for this.
Here is what you can do to set the feature gates flags for the Kubernetes engine RKE.

step 1: Open Rancher2.0 UI

step 2: View cluster in API

[image]

step 3: Click edit and modify the `rancherKubernetesEngineConfig` input box

[image]

- Find the services key.
- Then add extra args for kubelet in below format

  ```
  "services": {
  "etcd": { "type": "/v3/schemas/etcdService" },
  "kubeApi": {
      "podSecurityPolicy": false,
      "type": "/v3/schemas/kubeAPIService",
      "extraArgs": { "feature-gates": "PersistentLocalVolumes=true, VolumeScheduling=true,MountPropagation=true" }
  },
  "kubeController": { "type": "/v3/schemas/kubeControllerService" },
  "kubelet": {
      "failSwapOn": false,
      "type": "/v3/schemas/kubeletService",
      "extraArgs": { "feature-gates": "PersistentLocalVolumes=true, VolumeScheduling=true,MountPropagation=true" }
  }
  ```

step 4: Click show request .. you get a curl command and json request.

step 5: Verify the request body data which will be shown.

step 6: Make sure the key's which are not applicable are set to null. e.g `amazonElasticContainerServiceConfig`, `azureKubernetesServiceConfig`, `googleKubernetesEngineConfig` all need to null for me.

step 7: Click send request

You should get a response with status code 201. And your cluster will start updating. You can verify that your cluster RKE has updated by viewing the Cluster in API again.

Answer (score 3):

I was strugling with enabling feature gate TTLAfterFinished. (same as MountPropagation=true)

> Rancher v2.3.3

step 1: Open Rancher2.3.3 UI

step 2: Click edit cluster

step 3: Click the button "edit as YAML" next to "Cluster Options"

step 4: You need to add feature gate to all cluster services (see below)

step 5: add or edit extra_args similar to this:

```
    ...
        kube-api:
          extra_args:
            feature-gates: TTLAfterFinished=true
    ...
        kube-controller:
          extra_args:
            feature-gates: TTLAfterFinished=true
    ...
        kubelet:
          extra_args:
            feature-gates: TTLAfterFinished=true
    ...
```

Replace TTLAfterFinished with your feature gate. [LIST HERE](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/)

Answer (score 1):

alternative *(test is pending, blocked by https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/26261)*:

step 1: Open Rancher2.0 UI

step 2: Click edit for cluster (in menu with three vertical dots)

step 3: Click the button "edit as YAML" next to "Cluster Options"

step 4: find "services.kubelet" (or "services.WhatYouNeed")

step 5: add or edit `extra_args` similar to this:

```
    kubelet:
      extra_args:
        feature-gates: rancherKubernetesEngineConfig=true
```

(according to https://rancher.com/docs/rke/latest/en/config-options/services/services-extras/#extra-args)

step 6: click save (at bottom)

#### create new cluster

You can also edit "Cluster Options" as yaml when creating a new cluster. Probably this can also be included as an "rke template".

Comment: suggested to documentate in https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/27095