# Enabling feature gates on kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I am trying to enable feature gates on a Kubernetes cluster. I have tried using kubeadm call

```
kubeadm config images list --feature-gates TTLAfterFinished=true
```

however I get the error

```
unrecognized feature-gate key: TTLAfterFinished
```

I am using Rancher to build and deploy the cluster. I am using this site to determine the name of the feature gates to enable. https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this as well. Here is the solution to update the feature gates via Rancher API or Rancher UI. You can use the edited cluster via API feature as shown in the answer that worked for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51373855/5617140

Hope this helps.